# How to efficiently extract matching objects from an NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, sorting, search

I'm looking for the most efficient way to achieve the following task...

I have an array of Objects of type `Foo`, amongst other properties, `Foo` has a `latitude` and a `longitude` property. Given an array of many `Foo`'s, I need to extract the `Foo`'s with matching lat / long's into one new array.

I have implemented several solutions which are working, including iterating using a for loop, and a solution using an NSPredicate, but both of these methods involve multiple iterations through an array. This array could potentially have hundreds of thousands of records, so i'm looking for something i can use which will achieve the desired result in one pass.

EDIT: Adding some pseudo-code to describe the approach i've already taken and to better describe the problem...

```
NSMutableArray * matchingLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

for (Foo * checkingFoo in fooArray) {

    NSMutableArray * checkingArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:fooArray];
    [checkingArray removeObject:checkingFoo];        

    for (Foo * foo  in checkingArray) {

        // I have a method coded for comparing two coordinates
        if (checkingFoo.coordinate == foo.coordinate) { 

            [matchingLocations addObject:checkingFoo];                

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need several passes? Checking each element once should be enough.

Comment: Well this is probably where I'm doing it wrong, but for each item within the array, i go through and check every other item to see if it's a duplicate.

Comment: matching lat,long but with whom? do you want to remove the duplicate entries from same array?

Comment: You're searching for matches for several objects? Maybe show some code? If you need to check with more than one (and unrelated) values, this asks for O(m*n).

Comment: Added some sample code

Comment: What do you mean by "matching"?  Do you mean identical coordinates?  Do you mean within x metres?

Comment: Code doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Code makes perfect sense, it will extract all 'Foo' objects which have the same coordinates (lat/lon) as any other 'Foo' objects within the original array. These can then be removed from the original array. This code is working perfectly, all I wanted to know is if there is a more efficient way of doing it, which cescofry showed me perfectly.

Comment: Ah I see. The keywords are "unique" or "duplicate" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSSet will provide a collection of unique objects. In order to implement it properly however you need to define what does mean to be identical for the Foo object. You do that in your Foo class implementation rewriting the method isEqual: and the method hash.
In your Foo class:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
return (self.coordinate == [(Foo *)object coordinate]);
```

}

```
- (NSUInteger)hash {
return ([self.coordinate hash]);
```

}

Then everywhere in your code you can just use:

```
    NSArray *array; // Your array with multiple Foo objects potentiually duplicates
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:array];
```

Have a loo kat the Apple Documentation reference for:
[NSObject isEqual:] https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:

[NSSet setWithArray:]
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSSet/setWithArray:

Comment: Keep in mind that the set is not sorted. This may work in the given context, but may be limiting in general use when hash cannot or shouldn't be used that easily, i.e. when the same class is used elsewhere and several objects in the same location are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You are running two fast enumeration as for loop of same array. Which is not correct. If you want to compare the co-ordinates then excecute for loop of different array. And also you can add directly to mutable array if same for loop only you are using.

Comment: Sorry, That was my mistake in the pseudo-code, i have updated it to reflect what I am actually doing.

Comment: Why you are comparing with same array only ? i am not getting exactly what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare objects from the array, then I suggest you use NSSet instead of NSArray.

It is very easy to use and the below link is something you want because I resolved such a case using NSMutableSet :

[NSSet Tutorial](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsset.html)